# Is there a way to let form actions trigger when a typed search query partially, or fully matches any of the input datalist entries on iOS/Webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, reactjs, webkit

I am trying to build a search feature for a React app. I have reduced its implementation to a minimal reproducible example. I *think* the problem I am encountering might be be a browser bug.

Consider the following React code:

```js
function ProblematicForm() {
  const action = async (formData) => {
    // assume this is "use server". I _must_ extract the data from formData.
    // useState cannot be used to coordinate the value between this action and the input!
    alert(formData.get('search'))
  }

  return (
    <form action={action}>
      <input list="search" name="search" type="search" />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
      <datalist id="search">
        <option value="foo" />
        <option value="bar" />
        <option value="baz" />
      </datalist>
    </form>
  )
}
```

On Safari (WebKit), the datalist correctly renders:

[image: Safari shows datalist entries foo, bar and baz]

and **typing out partial or full match of a member of the datalist**, then hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> causes the form action to trigger.

[image: partial match triggers form action]

Now on iOS Chrome (also WebKit, latest version as of time of writing), ***typing out a partial* or full match, then hitting the <kbd>search</kbd> button on the iOS keyboard, does not trigger the form action**.

[image: search not working with fo query]

[image: search not working with foo query]

What *does* work is **selecting** (not typing!) a datalist entry from the dropdown box, then hitting <kbd>search</kbd> on the iOS keyboard:

[image: dropdown selected works]

Note that this **fails when selecting the datalist suggestion that sits above the keyboard**, which I assume is equivalent to typing out the datalist entry manually from an implementation perspective.

What also works is **typing something that doesn't match anything at all from the datalist**, then hitting the <kbd>search</kbd> button on the iOS keyboard.

[image: unmatch type works]

So either this is:

1. An iOS specific WebKit bug
2. I have misconfigured my `<input>` and `<datalist>` tags to prohibit *typed* rather than selected matches

What I am asking is:

1. if the problem is 1., is there a workaround to address this that preserves reasonable HTML `<form>` semantics and affordances?
2. If the problem is 2., what do I do to fix my `<form>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you might need to set the input type to text using

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

if the above code doesnt work you can try getting the keycode for the return button

```
$('search_field').observe('keyup',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            NAME.search($('search_field'));
        }
    });
```